# HTML SMS link & populating message

Tags: html, ios, iphone, sms

I am trying to set up a hyperlink in such a way that allows someone to tap it on a smartphone and be taken immediately to their default SMS messaging app to send an SMS.

There have been solutions posted here before to show how this is possible:

```
<a href="sms:[number]?body=[message]">Android</a>
<a href="sms:[number];body=[message]">iOS</a>
<a href="sms:[number]&body=[message]">iOS 8</a>
```

I have used PHP to detect which device the user is on so that the correct format can be used, but there have been some inconsistencies recently.

iPhone 4 doesn't seem to work with any of those, showing a blank message. iPhone 5C works with the semi-colon, but only populates the phone number and not the message. Old iPads around the same age as an iPhone 4 work fine.

In the past, these devices have all worked fine and so I can only assume a recent update somewhere has accidentally created bugs.

Does anyone have a workaround for those specific phones, or is there a definitive list anywhere that shows specific phones & what is required for each? It seems really odd that there are so many inconsistencies between devices.

Comment: Can you please specify the iOS version and not the hardware version, because this is most likely  a os version issue.

Comment: the iPhone 4 only support iOS 7.1 thus I think you have a iPhone 4S. Still this is weird behavior. I know that apple does not officially support the body property for text messages. See the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html